# Put results on a table, divided by all days of the week

Tags: c#, mysql, date, webmatrix

I'm trying to get the records of a DB to a table, however I'm struggling because I have to divide them for weekday and on each weekday they can be in the morning, afternoon, night, or all day.[image]

On the picture above it's how I want to display the information. To clarify

Item 1 - Weekday (Monday - 27/10/2014) and so on.

Then on the second column (Manhã = Morning) I want to show everything that was inserted on that morning.

(For example: Monday morning, can have 4 entries, but in the afternook it can have only 1, and 0 in the night.)

Above that table is the result on a webgrid for each day of the week. What I've done was:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT dataOcorrencia FROM relatoriosSemanais WHERE semana= '43'"
```

and put it on a webgrid, and it gets me all the weekdays from week 43, and yes the week will be dynamic.

But now I don't know how to get the records like I told you guys above.

My DB have the week, the period (morning, afternoon, night, allday), day.

Don't know if you can understand my problem.

```
27  26/10/2014 12:30    26/10/2014 13:58    Mobile  Outros  Alerta CC3  Clientes a ficar com carregamentos em processamento.    FECHADO 43  Sim Manhã   Criticidade Muito Elevada   Relatório SI        26-10-2014
28  26/10/2014 09:39    26/10/2014 11:45    Serviços Online Área de Cliente Alerta CC3  Área de Cliente indisponível    FECHADO 43  Sim Tarde   Criticidade Muito Elevada   Relatório SI        26-10-2014
29  26/10/2014 09:39    26/10/2014 11:45    Serviços Online Área de Cliente Alerta CC3  Área de Cliente indisponível    FECHADO 43  Sim Manhã   Criticidade Regular Relatório SI        26-10-2014
```

Comment: How do you define the boundary between morning, afternoon, and night?  Can you please show a few sample rows from your database?

Comment: I have a column that have the period of the day.

Comment: When the user insert to the db i have a dropdown with mornig, afternoon, night, all day

Comment: I can give the exanple in like 30m, not at computer right now.

Comment: i have put some rows from my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work week by week, you  need a simple formula for converting any `DATETIME` value into the date of the preceding Sunday.  This can be done as follows

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(record_date) -MOD(TO_DAYS(record_date) -1, 7))
```

(If your weeks begin on Mondays use `-2` instead of `-1`.)

Why do this? Because you can choose a week's worth of data with this sort of `WHERE` clause.

```
 WHERE record_date >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7)) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
   AND record_date <  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7))
```

Using that design pattern, I suggest you try something like this to set up your table.  You have not told us the names of your columns, so it is impossible to give you a perfect query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(record_date),'%W') AS weekday,
       SUM(Sim = 'Sim Manhã') AS `Manhã`,
       SUM(Sim = 'Sim Tarde') AS `Tarde`,
       SUM(Sim = 'Sim Noite') AS `Noite`,
       SUM(Sim = 'Sim Todo o Dia') AS 'Todo o Dia'
  FROM dataOcorrencia 
 WHERE record_date >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7)) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
   AND record_date <  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(NOW()) -1, 7))
 GROUP BY DATE(record_date)
```

This works because the value `Sim = 'Sim Manhã'` is `1` if the column `Sim` has the value `'Sim Manhã'` and zero otherwise.  So, summing the `1` values counts the rows where the condition is true.

One more thing: `DATE_FORMAT(...'%W')` yields day-of-week names. If you issue this command to MySQL right after you open your connection, you'll get those day names in Portuguese.

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'
```

Comment: Ollie Jones, thanks a lot for your help and set me on the right track, thanks for the explanation and your time.